# SSRS Report Parameter Stripped

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a report that uses a stored procedure as a dataset. I am building the report dialog using a UI builder class within Dynamics AX.

My parameters are being successfully passed to the dataset with the exception of my customers string. The format of which are the customer accounts separated by semicolons, eg.

```
"100019;100021;100234"
```

I have printed the parameter on the report and I get `"100019"` - only the first customer.

I have checked the report parameter in the PreRunModifyContract method of the controller class using  `dataContract.getValue('StoredProcedure_InvoiceAccount')` and at this point the value of the parameter is correct.

So my question is why and where is the parameter value changing, and how do I prevent it.

Comment: Have you tried using commas instead?  `SysQueryHelper` or something is the class I believe.

Comment: It's not something ridiculous like the original str variable in AX was only 6 characters in length before you even pass the variable as a parameter?...  I say this as my life gets ridiculous at times...

Comment: No, nothing like that, I do have a solution now. But the fact that the reporting services is treating semicolons as special characters suggests there is some built in functionality for multiselect parameters that I don't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does appear that the reporting services treat semicolons as special characters. The solution I came up with was to modify my string by changing all the semicolons to commas, but I did this in the PreModifyContract method instead of using SysQueryHelper. Obviously I then had to modify the logic in my stored procedure to look for commas instead of semicolons.